# Клик на родительский див через дочерний

Tags: javascript, события

При создании модального окна столкнулся с проблемой. Есть изображение, при клике на которое, открывается модальное окно, но на этом изображении есть несколько `<span>` (название, описание и т.д.).

При использовании `event.target`, если клик происходит на эти области `<span>`, то модальное окно не выводится. А если использовать `event.currentTarget`, то всплытие идет до самого контейнера с этими самыми изображениями (`works`).

Вопрос, как сделать , чтобы изображение открывалось при клике на родительский `<div>`, даже если клик произошел на его дочерний элемент?

Мой код:

```
<div class ="works">
    <div class="containerWorks">
        <h2 class="works_title"><span class = "line1">CHECK OUT SOME OF MY WORKS.</span></h2>
        <div class="works_img"  style ="background-image: url(1.jpg);">
            <div class="worksHover">
                <span class="works_span_plus">
                    +
                </span>
                <span class="works_span_name">
                    Menu <br>
                </span>
                <span class="works_span_name_desc">
                    description of project
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверку надо делать при клике такого вот вида.

```js
e.target.closest('название родительского блока') ? имя функции которую надо вызвать если в родительском элементе есть необходимый селектор : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Как простой вариант решения:

```
this.parentNode
```

?